# hosts can not be null - exception when creating POJO connection to MongoDB 4.2 database

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, tomcat9

In Mongo 3.6, the following code worked to connect to a database using automatic POJO mapping:

```
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                                      fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",
                                  MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).build());
```

In Mongo 4.2, the classes have change slightly.  Importantly, the `create()` method of the new MongoClients class doesn't support the `"localhost"` String parameter that the old constructor did.  This means that the example provided in the Quick Start - POJOs section of the documentation (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/) doesn't work.

```
33        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
34                                          fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
35       
36        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
37                                            .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
38                                            .build();
39        
40        mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

I'm running this on **Tomcat 9** and getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hosts can not be null
    com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.notNull(Assertions.java:37)
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:446)
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:43)
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.build(ClusterSettings.java:260)
    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:733)
    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:59)
    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.build(MongoClientSettings.java:481)
    com.ossltd.whm.MongoDB.<init>(MongoDB.java:38)
    ...
```

This is a single instance of MongoDB running on the same server as Tomcat.  How do I set the host value for this connection?  Or is there something else I should do to get the same type of connection as the first example?

Comment: URL to example?

Comment: It's a private development at the moment.  Is there some more information that you need that could be helpful?

Comment: I meant URL to documentation you are following, not your code.

Comment: :-)  Sorry.  I've updated the question and added the link.

Comment: "pojo" refers to the type of data that is inserted/queried. What is a "pojo connection"?

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/quick-start/ shows connection examples.

Comment: Yes, I looked through those connection examples, but they don't show how to include the PojoCodecRegistry.  The link I added to the question explains what that is, but using their example gives me the problem that I've described.

Comment: There is a page for pojo operations and there is a page for connecting to the deployment. Get the connection working, then tackle pojo objects.

Comment: I could run a _servlet program_ with Tomcat 9, MongoDB 4.2 and Java driver 4.0.4. I created the `MongoClient` with the same code from the example link (and your code). I could connect to the MongoDB server and read from a collection - no errors.  My database server runs on the default setting - localhost and port 27017 (I didn't have to specify the host or port).

Comment: Also, if you need to provide another host or/or port you can do so as shown in the example at: [MongoDB Driver Quick Start - Make a Connection](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/quick-start/). You can do the setting on the same `MongoClientSettings` object you are already creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by conflicting jars being included in the war file.

I only found this by accident when trying to compare my pom.xml to an older working project.  I mistakenly thought I was using the 3.6.0 jar files in this new project, but the Maven dependencies in Eclipse and using `mvn dependency:tree` were only showing the 4.0.4 jar files.

When I checked the actual content of the war file (and in the /WEB-INF/lib directory of my installed webapp), I found that it contained the Mongo 3.6.0 jars, the 4.0.4 legacy jar and the 4.0.4 sync jar files.  I couldn't find any references in my current project that would cause them to be included, although I had tried them previously.

The solution was to simply ensure that my build goal included `clean` before the `tomcat7:redeploy`.

It seems that the war file was being updated rather than re-created with the `tomcat7:redeploy` goal.